# Mongodb "patching" one collection results from other colection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've got let's say one collection "users":

```
[{ "User" : 
  { id: "1",
    phone: "111 111 111",
    login: "abc"
  },
  "Address" :
  { street: "Street",
    town: "NY"
  }
},
{ "User" : 
  { id: "2",
    phone: "222 222 222",
    login: "xyz"
  },
  "Address" :
  { street: "Street",
    town: "NY"
  }
}]
```

And now I have "updates" collection:

```
[{ "User" :
  { id: "1" },
   "Address": 
   { town: "LA" }
}]
```

All have common User.id field.

Now I'm trying to get data from "users" but updated with fields from "updates".

```
{ "User" : 
  { id: "1",
    phone: "111 111 111",
    login: "abc"
  },
  "Address" :
  { street: "Street",
    town: "LA" // <--- updated
  }
}
```

I want to use it in a Atlas function attached to an endpoint.

I tried:

```
aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "User.id": id
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "updates",
      localField: "User.id",
      foreignField: "User.id",
      as: "updates"
    }
  }
```

And I get additional "updates" where it exists, but with extra fields. How original "users" fields values map/override with values from "updates" when they're there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$mergeObjects`. You will need extra `$mergeObjects` for individual nested document fields(e.g. `Users`)

```js
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "User.id": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "updates",
      localField: "User.id",
      foreignField: "User.id",
      as: "updatesLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$updatesLookup",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$$ROOT",
          "$updatesLookup",
          {
            User: {
              "$mergeObjects": [
                "$User",
                "$updatesLookup.User"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "updatesLookup"
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/V7nkV9FMAQ6)

Comment: It ALMOST works! The only problem is I've lost other original "User" fields. In the example result in User there's "login" missing.

Comment: @Code10 updated the answer to add extra `$mergeObjects` for `User`. I am afraid that for nested document objects, you may need to do `$mergeObjects` one by one.

Comment: Now works perfect. I've added all object fields necessary for me in this query and works. FYI: If "updates" collection has more than 1 document with the same ids in the result you get both "variants" of complete objects - patched with 1st record and patched with 2nd record in "updates". I don't know if it satisfy me more that looking at the last update records but it may be a feature not a bug - I will control to have only 1 complete "update" record. Thank you very much. I appreciate your help!